# Django ORM Q and Async

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, orm

I'm using django with Telegram Bot

If i need to make ORM Query, i can do it like that

```
    all_offers = await sync_to_async(Offers.objects.filter, thread_sensitive=True)(
        status      = True,
    )
```

but not i need to make more difficult query with Q function like that

```
    all_offers = await sync_to_async(Offers.objects.filter, thread_sensitive=True)(
        status      = True,
        Q(some_field="1")|Q(another_field=2),
    )
```

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error says, you can not place positional parameters after keyword ones, so you should put the `Q` object first:

```
all_offers = await sync_to_async(Offers.objects.filter, thread_sensitive=True)(
    Q(some_field='1') | Q(another_field=2),
    status=True,
)
```

Using an asynchronous filter however does *not* make much sense: `.filter()` is lazy: that means that you only construct a `QuerySet` asynchronously, not fetch the records themselves in an asynchronous manner. The reason there is no <s>`.afilter(…)`</s>, <s>`.aannotate(…)`</s>, etc. is because these do not generate a query, only produce a new `QuerySet` that might (or will not) eventually make a database query.

You can make use of an `async for` when you enumerate over the queryset. For more information, see the [*Asynchronous support* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/async/#queries-the-orm).

Comment: how i can add here order_by intruction?

Comment: @Yuretz: just omit the `sync_to_async`, and work with `Offers.objects.filter(Q(some_field='1') | Q(another_field=2), status=True).order_by(..)` there is no reason to use an asynchronous for this. You should make the "consumer" asynchronous, not when you construct a `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write async context manager for this:

```py
async for offer in Offers.objects.filter(status=True, Q(some_field="1")|Q(another_field="2")):
    # Perform logic on the individual "offer"
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/

Answer (score 0):

```py
await sync_to_async(Region.objects.filter)(Q(title__icontains=region).first)()
```

is correct?